# EnableDelayedExpansion not working as expected with ECHO

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Forgive me if this has been asked before but my searches have come up with nothing similar....

I have a batch file that uses a for loop to go through a comma delimited file that is formatted like this...

`Pathname,client`

The batch is intended to pass the path to a logparser command which in turn sums a column of data. I am trying to get my results sent to a single file in which the client and results are listed on the same line like this...

```
client, sum
client, sum
```

However when I attempt to do so with echos and redirects (>>) the values end up on seperate lines like this...

```
client,
sum
client,
sum
```

In my search I noted that using the "SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION" should work but I have not had any luck. [SS64](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) I have tried variations of variables with no luck. The command is ran from a batch file, not command line.

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION ENABLEEXTENSIONS
for /f "tokens=1,2 skip=1 delims=," %%f in (faxreportnames.csv) do (
echo %%g,>>parse_page_counts.txt
logparser -i:csv "select sum(NUMPAGES) from %%f where FAX_STATUS = 'SUCCESSFUL'" -q:on -rtp:-1 -headers:off>>parse_page_counts.txt
)
```

I have a feeling it is something silly simple but after several hours of trying, I think I am missing it...

Edit for clarity:

- The issue is more where a CRLF is being added when using the echo
  statement. My searches said using the "EnableDelayedExpansion" should
  resolve the issue... I am aware using echo causes the CR\LF to be
  appended.
- The values in the .csv file being read are strictly text.
  First column is the path and path name of a .csv to be parsed. Second
  column is the client name.
- The values returned by %%f and %%g are correct.

Comment: Could you please revisit your question in order that we can understand what your issue is. From what I can see, `%%g` will have the value `<space>secondFieldOfEachLineFromfaxreportnames.csv` and you're running a command, `logparser -i:csv "select sum(NUMPAGES) from FirstFieldOfEachLineFromfaxreportnames.csv where …`.

Comment: I'm going to assume that your question, which has nothing whatsoever to do with delayed expansion, is really how do I write to a file without a CarriageReturn&LineFeed pair! In which case, what did you find when searching this site from the search bar at the top of each page? because that question has been asked and answered before.

Comment: Redirection is line based. Always a CRLF at the end.

Comment: @user14797724, it's not the redirection that appends a line-break, it's the `echo` command; you could use `< nul set /P ="%%g,"` instead of `echo %%g,` to avoid the line-break (but it may fail depending on the value of `%%g`)…

Comment: `My searches said using the "EnableDelayedExpansion" should ... [remove the CRLF]`. I'd like to know your source(s) for that. As far as I know, delayed expansion does nothing like that.

Comment: SS64.com has been where I found better details for the EnableDelayedExpansion. The link in my post is where I saw "This behaviour can be changed using SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion"

Comment: The behavior that's being mentioned is for the variables to be read and replaced when the line is read in by the interpreter instead of when the line is executed.

Answer (score 0):

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION ENABLEEXTENSIONS
for /f "tokens=1,2 skip=1 delims=," %%f in (faxreportnames.csv) do (
 logparser -i:csv "select sum(NUMPAGES) from %%f where FAX_STATUS = 'SUCCESSFUL'" -q:on -rtp:-1 -headers:off>"tempfilename.txt"
 for /f "usebackq delims=" %%c in ("tempfilename.txt") do echo %%g,%%c>>"parse_page_counts.txt"
)
```

(UNTESTED as I don't have `logparser`)

Uses and leaves `tempfile.txt` - a filename of your own choosing.

I've used quotes around `tempfile.txt` to avoid the spaces-in-names issue if the chosen `tempfile.txt` is in the typical `%temp%` directory. The `usebackq` is required if the filename is quoted but should be omitted if the temporary filename is not quoted.

I'm sure this could be done more cleanly, but without `logparser`, I'm not able to test.